# USB Issues - Mobo or jack/cable?

Tags: usb, motherboard

On a machine I built I'm getting some odd behavior on the case USB jacks. I hook up a wireless keyboard and mouse and every now-and-then (every 3 min or so usually) the keyboard will type extra strokes. Mouse doesn't jump around. Now I've fried two flash drives on those jacks as well - they won't read on other computers after being on this one for a bit.

I replaced the keyboard/mouse and tested the old on another computer. I'm fairly certain the issue is related to these front USB jacks. How can I test whether the issue is the jack/cable or the mobo?

Thank you.

Comment: Re-check your USB cables on the mobo, and make sure that they're plugged in the correct pins.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the dead flash drives so you can see the bare circuit board and the contacts. If there's burn marks or something melted, you have something really wrong, either a bad mobo or wires crossed. If you've got a voltmeter, you may want to check the voltage coming out of the front usb header on the mobo to make sure the pins are correct. (making sure the contacts for the voltmeter don't touch the mobo itself) Look online to see if other people have had similar issues for your specific mobo and case models.

Comment: Please only ask clarifying questions in the comment area, not in your answers. Otherwise, it may be recommended for deletion as a comment. I suggest you edit your answer to remove it.